# Block html post form on certain input

Tags: html, post

I have a simple form:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" size="65" maxlength="34" pattern="^[123][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34}$" placeholder="Your BTC Address" required>
```

and was wondering if it's possible, when certain btc addresses are inserted, the form to not work. like a btc address ban.

Thank you

Comment: It is possible to enforce in your front end code, but any bad actor with a little know-how would be able to bypass it, so it is not a replacement for proper validation in the back end code.

Comment: Pay attenion to @anied answer !

Answer (score 0):

You can control input using jQuery before post form (submit).
https://api.jquery.com/submit/